# Ways to better utilize hops with a coffeepress?

Tags: hops

I am thinking about trying to utilize the hops I use better by combining late addition and early addition via a coffeepress.

The basic idea is to make a hops-tea in the coffeepress, let it sit for maybe 5 minutes, then press the hops down and pour the tea into a sanitized bottle/bucket and then add the hops from  the press to the boil for the full 60 minutes.

What I hope to achieve is to preserve the aromas you get by late-addition but still get the full bittering out of it.

Has anyone tried this? Would I be combining advantages or disadvantages with this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I've tried it.  The tea is harsh and vegetal and nothing I'd want in my beer.  Also, using hot water will isomerize the hops to some extent, so bitterness will be left behind in the press when you add the hops to the wort.  I understand your desire to get more out of your hops, but it just doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 2):

By boiling for 60 minutes, whatever you extract from the hops into your 'tea', you will be eliminating any of the aroma, and most all of the flavor components from the hops.

The 60 minute addition is your bittering addition, and this is the quality you will get. If you are looking for hop flavor/aroma, I would recommend starting by experimenting with 10(more flavor) - 0(more aroma) minute additions, and/or dry hop(aroma) additions.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about adding the tea immediately, but after flameout.